# Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java taking lot of time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used AWS SDK for java to copy from one bucket to another 
File Size : 299mb

Code:

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new    CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucketName,sourceKeyName,destinationBucket,destinationKeyName);

s3client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
```

It is taking 1min 20 sec to copy

But if do it with s3cmd cp command it is taking 33sec to copy the same file.
Kindly suggest any solution to speed up the copy process using java sdk

Comment: Are you two buckets in the same region ?

Comment: yes.. they are in same region